# How to set project parameters on SSIS step in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl

I have stored procedure that accept parameters that I have to set to dynamically created agent job responsible for running SSIS package.

I tried to execute the package directly from my application, but it should be run as different user.

```
--Add database server
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver
    @job_id =  @jobId,
    @server_name = @databaseServer;

--Add SSIS step
DECLARE @jobCommand nvarchar(max)
SELECT @jobCommand = N' /ISSERVER  "\SSISDB\MyPackage.dtsx" '
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /SERVER ' + @ssisServer + N' /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E'
--Set variables
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /Par "\"$Package::varFundCode\"";"\"' + @fundCode + '\""'
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /Par "\"$Package::varInitiatedBy\"";"\"' + @initiatedBy + '\""'
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /Par "\"$Package::varPackageTimestamp\"";"\"' + @timestamp + '\""'
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /Par "\"$Package::varReprint\"";"' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @isReprint) + '"'
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /Par "\"$Package::varRunID\"";"\"' + CONVERT(nvarchar(20), @runId) + '\""'
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /Par "\"$Package::varShouldEmail\"";"' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @shouldEmail) + '"'
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /Par "\"$Package::varTestModeOn\"";"' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @testModeOn) + '"'
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /SET \Package.Variables[User::varEmailRecipient].Value;"' + @emailRecipient + '"'
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /Par "Projects::Connections[Database connection manager].Properties[ServerName]";"' + @databaseServer + ''
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /Par "Project::Connections[Database connection manager].Properties[InitialCatalog]";"' + @dbName + ''


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
    @job_id = @jobId,
    @step_name = N'Execute vendor SSIS package',
    @subsystem = N'SSIS',
    @command = @jobCommand,
    @proxy_name = 'remittances_proxy'
```

how is the right syntax of setting the parameters and connection variable,
because I receive either 
  Argument "Projects::Connections[Database" for option "parameter" is not valid.  The command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed.

on the Job history or
 Environment reference Id: NULL.  Description: The data type of the input value is not compatible with the data type of the 'Boolean'.

I tried passing true/false and 0/1 for boolean parameters?

Comment: Sorry. I deleted my answer as that was how to run packages with a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Refering on the following official documentation:

- [dtexec Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-2017)

> You can also set connection manager properties by using parameters. You use the CM prefix to denote a connection manager parameter.
>
> In the following example, InitialCatalog property of the SourceServer connection manager is set to ssisdb

```
/parameter CM.SourceServer.InitialCatalog;ssisdb
```

> In the following example, ServerName property of the SourceServer connection manager is set to a period (.) to indicate the local server.

```
/parameter CM.SourceServer.ServerName;.
```

---

Based on that, change the following code lines

```
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /Par "Projects::Connections[Database connection manager].Properties[ServerName]";"' + @databaseServer + ''
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /Par "Project::Connections[Database connection manager].Properties[InitialCatalog]";"' + @dbName + ''
```

To

```
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /Par CM.Databaseconnectionmanager.ServerName;"' + @databaseServer + '"'
SELECT @jobCommand = @jobCommand + N' /Par CM.Databaseconnectionmanager.InitialCatalog;"' + @dbName + '"'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hadi. I don't know if it works however, because I still get this error:
 Failed to execute IS server package because of error 0x80131904. Server: ...\SQL01, Package path: \myPackage.dtsx, Environment reference Id: NULL.  Description: The data type of the input value is not compatible with the data type of the 'Boolean'.  I tried passing them like "true/false" or "0/1" but in both cases doesn't worked. I think it could be that in the stored procedure I am converting it to string in order to pass it like a command?